# Issue displaying uitableview in UIViewController - Not aligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I dragged a `uitableview` component to my `UIViewController` in the `Storyboard`.

It appears as

[image]

Then when I ran the application, there's a space on the side. How to prevent this?
[image]

Note: Initially this application was enabled autoLayout, and I removed it later on. Hope there's no effect for this error.

Comment: are you using custom cells?

Comment: Did you get it working with one of the solutions provided?

Comment: Still it doesn't work

Comment: It fits for an iPhone 5S but not 6. How can i make it work for all iPhones

Comment: This issue can be handled with both "Auto Layout" and "Auto Resizing". 
I use the way which i mentioned in my answer below.
So if Auto Layout is enabled, the way to approach this problem is different.
If Auto Layout is Unchecked/Disabled then you can use my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add constraints on your tableview.

If you don't know how to, here is a simple step by step :

1. Right clic or ctrl+drag the `tableview` (on the left side list) to
   `View`.
2. Select Top space to top layout guide Repeat with `Bottom
   space to bottom layout guide`
3. Repeat with `Leading space to
   container margin`
4. Repeat with `Trailing space to container margin`

That should fix your issues.

Comment: Well the user have mentioned that autolayout is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on this link will surely help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26708486/3396270

Though its Table view in your case you can use it with all the components by changing the settings as per their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you uncheck the `Translucent` property of your Navigation Bar, it's going to fix it.

[image][image]

Comment: I don't have such property in my storyboard

Comment: Do you find the navigation bar in navigation controller hierarchy ? I add a picture to find it.

Comment: Sorry, i believed you wanted to remove the top space... My answer is not for the side space.

Comment: I want to remove the side space.

Answer (score 0):

Check your screen size in `Storyboard`:

[image]

And make sure you are running the application on same size of Simulator as in your `storyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `AutoLayout` then just write this code in your `viewDidLoad` Method

```
[tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight];
```

You could also set the `AutoresizingMask` from your `nib` file.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the xcode are you using? If it's okay with 5s and not okay with 6 and 6+ then you should change the size of the table manually or use autolayout. Storyboard which you'v used should have optimised for devices below 6. I you're using @3x image for splash screen then your app supports 6 and 6+ but it uses the same table size as what it is designed for 5s device size on simulator.

Solutions-

1. Use auto layout so this will solve the issue itself.
2. Else create outlet for table and changes it size according to the device width and height.

I have released an app using the above 2 solutions and its in the store now.